# I found a strange bit of C++ syntax

Tags: c++

```
 while(variable & 0x08)
```

I found this in a do while loop, the variable in question is technically the 4th index in a 16bit int array. The while loop itself doesn't modify that array.

honestly I'm not sure what the syntax does.

Comment: It runs until the result of the bitwise AND is zero.

Comment: What type does `variable` have?

Comment: @Jefffrey An integral type, or it won't compile.

Comment: @JamesKanze, with an overloaded `operator&`, yes, it would compile.

Comment: @JamesKanze - As it is C++ the `&` operator could be overloaded

Comment: Then read your book and find out!

Comment: OK, I missed that.  In well written code, of course, such an overloaded operator would only exist on "integer-like" types.  But since the author also fails to compare the results to `0`, we can assume that it isn't well written code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the *bitwise and* operator. Each bit of the result is set if the corresponding bit of both operands is set. So this loops while the fourth bit of `variable` is set.

That's assuming that `variable` is an integer type. If it's a class type, then the operator has been overloaded and could do anything.

Comment: Are you sure? How can you the behavior of this code without knowing what the type and value of `variable` is?

Comment: @Jefffrey: Indeed, I was assuming an integer type. I've stated my assumption now.

Comment: so a single & is also an & as well as a &&?

Comment: @Valarauca: I'm not sure what you mean. `&` is an operator, `&&` is a different operator (*logical*, rather than *bitwise*, *and*). Your introductory book should describe all the operators.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I always thought &variable meant its location in memory and && meant a logical and. This was my confusion on this question since 0x08 isn't a pointer.

Comment: @Valarauca: As a *unary* operator (i.e with just one operand as in `&x`) it takes the address. As a *binary* operator (i.e. with two operands as in `x & y`) it's the bitwise *and* operator. Your introductory book should describe all the operators.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the type of `variable`. This happens because the `operator&` can be overloaded. For example consider this code:

```
class some {};

bool operator&(const some&, int) {
    return true;
}
```

If you declare a variable `some variable;` and perform your:

```
while(variable & 0x08)
```

you would incur in an infinite loop.

If `variable` is an integral type, the loop will continue executing its body until the fourth bit of `variable` is not set to `1`. This is because the bit representation for `0x08` is:  `1000`. Therefore the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) will only be able to return a bit representation of `0` if the fourth bit of `variable` is set to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This is either a bitwise operation on an integer type, `variable`, in which case the loop will execute until the 4th bit of `variable` is 0, or it is a type that has an overloaded `operator&`, in which case it will run until the result of `operator&(T&, int)` (where `T` is the type for `variable`) returns 0 (or rather, something that does not equate to a non-zero conditional).